# How to read a list into an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, list

I've got a `.txt` file like this:

```
1039812323
2534563457
3457346731
2525146715
```

How do I pass this into an array and then access it's elements by index?

Comment: Assuming you want an array of strings without newline characters, you could write `File.read(file_name).split(/\n+/)`. That also works if the file contains blank lines (which would be disregarded).

Comment: What have you tried? If you show us your code, we can try to help you eliminate any bugs you have, but [so] is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array

```
File.readlines("a.txt")
```

take care that you are going to have an string with "\n" at the end of each number

```
["1039812323\n", "2534563457\n", "3457346731\n", "2525146715\n"]
```

Then you can use any ruby's array iterator (each, collect, inspect, map, etc)

Comment: So I'd use `lines.sub! '\n', ''` to take care of that?

Comment: rather call `.chomp` on the string when you need to access it. i.e. `lines.map(&:chomp)`

Comment: yes or if you want to have as integer you can do File.readlines("a.txt").map{|value| value.to_i}  or if you still want to work with strings File.readlines("a.txt").map {|value| value.chomp("\n")}

Comment: I like @maxpleaner 's solution, now if I'm in a loop and I want to access the first element and `.chomp` the `\n` how would that be done?

Comment: How does that help me for the next element? In pseudocode I'm thinking something like this: `lines = File.readlines("a.txt")` then `lines.map(&:chomp)[$i]` while I'm in the loop...

Comment: @HoracioBranciforte, what about substring? Can you do this: `f[$i][0...10]` where `f` is my array and `f[$i]` is the ith element of `f` and `f[$i][0...10]` is the first ten characters of the ith element of `f`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the other part of my question (*"...and then access it's elements by index?"*) vis-a-vis the `\n` caveat using Horacio Branciforte's method, this is a quick way to cut the `\n` off for ith element of `f` where `f` is the array `File.redlines("a.txt")`:

```
f[$i][0..10]
```

Of course, this only works if you know that the data coming in is of fixed length indefinitely across all elements in the array.

Comment: It's prettier too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
array = []
File.open("path_to_file").each_line do |line|
    array.push(line.chomp) # if you need '\n' then ommit chomp
end
# to iterate through the whole array
array.each do |ele|
    puts ele
end
# or to access by index
puts array[0] # to print the first value
```